# Golang: how to spin up a process with arbitrary arguments during a unit test?

Tags: shell, unit-testing, go, process

**What am I trying to do?**

-> Run a unit test which scans running processes and can extract `value` from the process list by "scanning" (looking into cmd lines by name) for the proc name (`sh`)

**What is not working**?

-> The code below seems to be flaky, especially on Mac (tests need to run on Mac and linux). Haven't identified why yet

**What did I try**?

-> Spin up a background process with `sh` and custom extra args (`sh` shouldn't crash) which sleeps so that I have time to look into the process list during the test and extract the value.

Code so far:

```
s := []string{"-c", `sleep 20; -` + arg + ` ` + value}
cmd := exec.Command("sh", s...) 
err := cmd.Start()
go func() {
    res := checkProcs("sh", arg)
    //kill cmd and test verification
}
```

I am happy to give up the `sh` approach, I just need something which "survives" the go routine and can be scanned for `value`. I was also thinking about some custom compile but couldn't find how to compile something on the file during a test.

Comment: Worth noting that because this interacts with externalities, this is not a unit test.

Comment: From the go code there is no visible reason to be flaky. Can you add a sample of a not flaky and a flaky command string?

Comment: So the above code runs a process like this: `sh -c sleep 20; -arg value`. And it seems to be flaky on Mac only...

Comment: The issue seems to be that `checkProcs` MIGHT be done BEFORE the actual background proc is up??? I tried with a small Sleep before launching the go routine and it SEEMS to be a bit better. Letting it run more to see if flakyness is gone indeed.

Comment: Wait for 0.1 second after `cmd.Start`. And you don't need to check for `sh` processes - cmd can provide you with PID and the state of the spawned process.